# How to change the language of Speech to Text in IBM Cloud?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I want to try the speech to text in Japanese. I refer to the following web site.
https://www.ibm.com/think/jp-ja/watson/ai-transcription/

I changed the audio file in Japanese, but the result of the analysis was English.
Please tell me how to change the language?

I used the following command in command prompt.

```
curl -X POST -u <username>:<password>
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @<path>audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

According to the Web site 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/input.html
there is a parameter `model`, 
so that I tried to add the parameter like `model:ja-JP_BroadbandModel`.
However the result of analysis didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Official API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?curl#recognize_sessionless_nonmp12), the `model` is a `query parameter`, like the `keywords_threshold` parameter and you can check in the official example from IBM Developers that they insert this parameter in the `url`, like the example:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file1.flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file2.flac"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5"
```

You can verify in this cURL the *last parameter* is `keywords_threshold`. So, you need to do the same in your cURL to specify the `model` parameter.

Example:

```
curl -X POST -u <username>:<password>
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @<path>audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true&model=ja-JP_BroadbandModel"
```

- Official API Reference using [cURL](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?curl#recognize_sessionless_nonmp12).